# WSO2 API Manager - Analytics

Tags: wso2, analytics, api-manager

When starting the wso2 API Manager Analytics 2.1.0 I get the error below. The DB is Oracle 11g with H2 for Carbon.

```
[2017-05-03 14:15:16,504] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceComponent} -  Error in activating analytics data service: null
java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore$RDBMSResultSetIterator.next(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:881)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore$RDBMSResultSetIterator.hasNext(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:843)
```

https://pastebin.com/jAkNQaMZ

Comment: Can u share the master-datasource.xml content without the sensible data?

Comment: @Pubci Here is master-datasource.xml for analytics https://pastebin.com/Z3J5D5dF

Comment: My issue was to do with the Stats DB. The tables weren't created for some reason. I ran another setup and this created the tables.

Comment: Did you start the server with -Dsetup ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and was able to solve this by upgrading the component "org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms-x.x.x" from 1.3.0 to 1.3.6.

Steps:

- Stop the analytics Server
- Remove the existing "org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms-1.3.0.jar" file from /repository/components/plugins folder
- Copy the "org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms-1.3.6.jar" file to /repository/components/dropins folder
- Start the server